# Отличия SwingUtilities.invokeLater и SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing

В каком случаи необходимо использовать `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, а в каком `SwingWorker`?

Comment: См. основной сайт: [Java - Difference between SwingWorker and SwingUtilities.invokeLater() (2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829364)